# Calling a method within a method (UIColor). Beginner

Tags: objective-c, uicolor, class-method

I am basically trying to make a method that enables me to get random colors for drawing. I have created a method like this:

```
-(UIColor*)randomColour
{
    NSArray *colourArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor redColor],
                                                     [UIColor blueColor],
                                                     [UIColor greenColor],nil];
    UIColor *colour = [colourArray objectAtIndex:rand()%3];

    [colourArray release];
    return colour;
}
```

and I WANT to call it like this

```
[[UIColor [self randomColour]] setStroke];
```

or like this

```
[[UIColor randomColour] setStroke];
```

but both fails. What is it that I don't understand?

For the second option I get a warning:

> "class method '+randomColour' not found"

I have tried reading up on class methods but can't see why it's cussing about it. Any quick pointers?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
[[self randomColour] setStroke];
```

Comment: Now however I have a memory management problem. If I release the colourArray in the top function it crashes... Does
UIColor *colour = [colourArray objectAtIndex:X]

only make it retain one specific entry of the array? The Array gets a return of 0 and subsequently releases all of it's children and itself?

How should I manage the memory of the the Array properly?

Comment: Since you are not allocating the memory, you should not release the `colorArray`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have defined `randomColour` in your own class, you simply do:

```
[[self randomColour] setStroke];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
+(UIColor*)randomColour
```

instead of

```
-(UIColor*)randomColour
```

Comment: What would this gain me? I tried it, and didn't work. And as far as I can see it shouldn't be a class method, no?

Comment: The difference between `+` and `-` is exactly the difference between class and instance method. If you want to call the method in the way you asked you should do as I said. What do you mean with "didn't work"?